# Can I replace mysql large table with cratedb

Tags: mysql, database, crate, nosql

I have a mysql table with around 200 million records and this will soon grow to 2 billion. I am looking at options , sharding in mysql or use a different database like Cratedb. 
These record have 12 columns with 3  Full-Text indexed columns and a mysql style "like" query is very common.

For testing 
I have create tables in Cratedb with 10 million records of dummy data and the queries are performing excellent. This server is a C3 Large instance with SSD on AWS. Seems great for my application at least for now

But before going ahead I would like to learn what are other guys experiences with Cratedb
Is there some comparison available of Mysql vs Cratedb, ( Searching for Cratedb on google gets auto corrected to createdb :( :(  )

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [vitess.io](http://vitess.io), which offers sharding on top of MySQL.
PS: I work on the project.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the decision to quickly based on other reviews. I tried CrateDb and performance was even worse than MySQL. Joins performs very badly.

Follow this link it might help you test with the same data.

https://crate.io/a/improving-on-joins/

https://blog.m7w3.de/how-was-the-weather-in-germany.html